# How to get "Delete Playlist" confirmation popup back in banshee?

Tags: banshee

At some point while deleting playlists in Banshee and seeing the confirmation popup that asks if I'm sure I want to delete, I checked the "Don't ask this question again" box. How do I undo this and make the confirmation popup show up again when deleting playlists?

Update: I found the .config/banshee-1/banshee.db configuration file and looked around with sqlitebrowser to see if I could find that setting, but I didn't see anything that looked like the setting I want (it's entirely possible that I missed something though).

(Xubuntu 14.04, Banshee 2.6.2)